# Upgrade/Convert AJAX.NET controls in a web site converted to Visual Studio 2013 from VS 2005

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-ajax, upgrade

Our client wants to upgrade an existing web application that uses AJAX.NET and Framework 2.  They want the application converted to Visual Studio 2013 from Visual Studio 2005, so that it uses Framework 4.5.

**My question is: what about the AJAX.NET controls? How can they be migrated?**

I suppose the controls have to be replaced one by one for the new controls that come with the new version of AJAX.NET.  Is there another way?  Is it possible to convert the controls automatically using some tool?

We don't have VS2013 yet so we cannot test, but I would like to know how the upgrade can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was necessary to upgrade or convert the AJAX controls when the project is upgraded to other version of Visual Studio and is targeting a newer version of the framework.  That is why I asked the question.  But I could test by converting the project with VS 2010 (not VS 2013 yet) and targeting framework 4.  The result is that there is no need to upgrade AJAX controls.  The same version that works with framework 2 works with framework 4.